# using LIMIT and ORDER BY with LEFT JOIN in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I'm a bit new to `JOIN` and I'm finding it difficult to understand how I can query one table with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` and using only `ORDER BY` on my `JOINED` 'right' table I think it is? So Basically if I was to query the two tables individually I would use these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY dateSubmitted DESC LIMIT ?,5
```

'?' standing for my `bind_param()` because I'm creating a pagination. Now for my 'right' Second table:

```
SELECT * FROM postcomments WHERE postcomments.postID = posts.ID ORDER BY dateSubmitted DESC
```

As far as my understanding goes to 'link' the two tables together I want to be using `LEFT JOIN` so that I will receive all my data from the 'left' table (being posts).

```
SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN postcomments ON postcomments.postID = posts.ID
```

Now I can do this but I'm unsure where I would but my `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` for both tables?
I've seen several different ways and I think this is what's getting me confused like I've seen this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts p ORDER BY posts.dateSubmitted DESC LIMIT ?,5 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM postcomments 
WHERE postscomments.postID = p.ID ORDER BY postcomments.dateSubmitted);
```

But I'm really unsure how to structure my query :S Any help appreciated :)

Comment: can you explain the idea behind putting limit on "both" tables with help of a scenario?

Comment: There's only a limit on the table posts. The postcomments table is `ORDERED` but not limited. Only the posts table is limited as I want to create a pagination. Like 0 to 5, then 5 to 10 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be at the end like this:

```
Select * from
(SELECT * FROM posts  ORDER BY dateSubmitted DESC LIMIT ?,5) as tempPost
LEFT JOIN postcomments on (postscomments.postID = tempPost.ID)
```

Comment: Now I thought that but that limits the `JOIN`ed table's results as well as the left table.

Comment: use multiple order by `posts.dateSubmitted , postcomments.dateSubmitted`